# Find the maximum number of rows with same character in 2D array that can be obtained by flipping columns?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You are given a M X N 2D array which can only have the characters 'a' or 'b'. The only allowed operation is flipping a column so every 'a' in that column would become a 'b' and vice versa. You are allowed any number of column flips. Find the maximum number of rows which has only 'a' or only 'b'.

The first line of input will give the matrix dimensions and the rest of the lines will represent each row of the matrix.

```
Input:
3 3
a a b
b b b
b b a

Output: 
2
```

Explanation:
Flipping column 3 will make row 1 consist of only 'a' and will make row 2 consist of only 'b'.

```
After flipping column 3:
a a a
b b a
b b b
```

Can someone please provide the solution to this question and explain it? It would also be helpful to provide the code (preferably in Java or Python).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Each column is flipped at most once(because flipping it `k` times is equivalent to flipping it `k mod 2` times). Thus, there is set of columns that will be flipped exactly once. The rest of the columns are not touched.
2. Let's take a look at a fixed row. If we want it to have only `a`, we should flip all columns that contain `b` in this row(and vice versa). That's why each row gives us to sets: a set of columns with `a` and a set of columns with `b`. Obviously, they are never equal to each other.
3. Now we can just generate two sets for each row and find the most frequent set. Its number of occurrences is the answer.

And here is an idea how to implement it in a very simple way: instead of generated sets explicitly, we can just generate two strings for each row: a result of concatenation of all elements in this row and its complement(by complement  I mean a string where all `a` are substituted by `b` and vice versa). Now we just need to find the most frequent string. We can do it using a `HashMap`. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Computes the complement of the string.
 */
private String getComplement(String string) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        builder.append(string.charAt(i) == 'a' ? 'b' : 'a');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

/**
 * Solves the problem for the matrix.
 */
public int getMaxRows(String[] matrix) {
    Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    for (String row : matrix) {
        count.put(row, count.getOrDefault(row, 0) + 1);
        String complement = getComplement(row);
        count.put(complement, count.getOrDefault(complement, 0) + 1);
    }
    return Collections.max(count.values());
}
```

Comment: did you try this out? it would be helpful to see the code for it.

Comment: @SalmanMohammed No, I haven't implemented it. But it looks pretty straightforward(for instance, in Java, we can just use a `HashSet` of `List`s).

Comment: i don't think this works. why are you incrementing the count value for every row without checking how many characters are the same in that row?

Comment: @SalmanMohammed A row is  String. For example, for your input the `matrix` is `{"aab", "bbb", "bba"}`.

Comment: @SalmanMohammed What makes you think that it is not correct? Do you have a test case it fails?

Comment: yeah but how do you know that the max value in the map will always return the max number of rows? flipping column 1 only in the above example would produce "bab" in row 1 and that string is never represented in the HashMap. how do you know that flipping column 1 will not be the optimal move? the only strings in the map will be {aab, bba, bbb, aaa}

Comment: i am not saying you are wrong. i am just trying to understand your solution better because i do not get how this would work now.

Comment: @SalmanMohammed For any string that is not in the map the answer is 0.